# Singleton pattern for sharing data between objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton

I'm trying to pass data around objects using singleton pattern. Here is my code

SearchData.m

```
@implementation SearchData
@synthesize theName = _theName;

-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _theName = @"Default";
    }
    return  self;
}

static SearchData *sharedSingleton = NULL;

+(SearchData *)sharedSearchData
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedSingleton == NULL) 
        {
            sharedSingleton = [[self alloc]init];
        }
        return sharedSingleton;
    }
}
@end
```

FirstView.m

...

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        SearchData *data = [SearchData sharedSearchData];
        self.aName = [data theName];
    }
    return self;
}
```

...

The problem is that I get

`Incompatible pointer types sending NSString to parameter of type NSStream.`

What is wrong here ?
How to pass data to  aName ivar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your declaration of `aName`, did you mistype `NSString` as `NSStream`? Stranger things have happened.

Comment: Yeah... aName was declared as NSStream instead of NSString

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the little checkmark at left. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because searchdata (NSStream) doesn't go into an NSString. 
Try:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:searchData ...
```